# Segmentation fault in node server from couchbase

Tags: node.js, segmentation-fault, couchbase

I'm getting a segfault when I make a request to my node server on an ec2 instance. The issue appears to be with couchbase, according to this log from node-segfault-handler. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to interpret this.

```
App listening on port 1337
PID 1932 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x0
/var/www/html/app/profile/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault_handler.node(+0x102d)[0x7fd3ca1b502d]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf5b0)[0x7fd3ca76a5b0]
/var/www/html/app/profile/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node(_ZN9Couchnode11ValueFormat6encodeEN2v86HandleINS1_5ValueEEENS0_4SpecERNS_10BufferListEPjPPcPmRNS_5CBExcE+0xb7)[0x7fd3c9f6e617]
/var/www/html/app/profile/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node(_ZN9Couchnode12StoreCommand12handleSingleEPNS_7CommandERNS_10CommandKeyEN2v86HandleINS5_5ValueEEEj+0x310)[0x7fd3c9f66990]
/var/www/html/binder-1337.com/profile/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node(_ZN9Couchnode7Command13processSingleEN2v86HandleINS1_5ValueEEES4_j+0xf5)[0x7fd3c9f64995]
/var/www/html/app/profile/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node(_ZN9Couchnode7Command13processObjectEN2v86HandleINS1_6ObjectEEE+0x58)[0x7fd3c9f64ab8]
/var/www/html/app/profile/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node(_ZN9Couchnode7Command7processEPFbPS0_RNS_10CommandKeyEN2v86HandleINS4_5ValueEEEjE+0x85)[0x7fd3c9f64b65]
/var/www/html/app/profile/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node(_ZN9Couchnode13CouchbaseImpl13makeOperationINS_12StoreCommandEEEN2v86HandleINS3_5ValueEEERKNS3_9ArgumentsERT_+0x89)[0x7fd3c9f5d289]
/var/www/html/app/profile/node_modules/couchbase/build/Release/couchbase_impl.node(_ZN9Couchnode13CouchbaseImpl8SetMultiERKN2v89ArgumentsE+0x260)[0x7fd3c9f5a440]
node[0x5c0abd]
[0x31e89f10618e]
```

From here, how might I go about figuring out what the problem is?

Comment: What version of libcouchbase (cbc version will tell you) and what version of the nodeJS client?

Opening up a defect at http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/JSCBC might be a better way of going about this problem.